# Casting an IEnumerable to IEnumerable<T> with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, ienumerable

So, I need to call a third party method, that has a signature like this

`ThirdPartyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)`

My problem is I don't know the type of my object at compile time.

At compile time I have this

```
IEnumerable myObject;
Type typeOfEnumerableIHave;
```

Sooo..can reflection help me out here somehow?

for simplicity sake, pretend I have a method like this

```
void DoWork(IEnumerable items, Type type)
{
   //In here I have to call ThirdPartyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> items);
}
```

Comment: In which context do you have this `IEnumerable myObject;`? Could you show a little bit more of your code?

Comment: @BrunoLM I have added a bit more, I'm not sure if it will help or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have `IEnumerable myObject;` and signature like `ThirdPartyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)` you are able to use `Cast()`:

```
ThirdPartyMethod(myObject.Cast<T>())
```

If you don't know the `T` type at the compile time you should provide it at runtime.

Consider you third-party library looks like this

```
public static class External
{
    public static void ThirdPartyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

if you have following

```
Type theType = typeof(int); 
IEnumerable myObject = new object[0];
```

you can get generic methods `ThirdPartyMethod` and `Cast` at the runtime

```
var targetMethod = typeof(External).GetMethod("ThirdPartyMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
var targetGenericMethod = targetMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { theType });

var castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
var caxtGenericMethod = castMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { theType });
```

Finally you call the method:

```
targetGenericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { caxtGenericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { myObject }) });
```

Comment: I don't know the correct way to say this, but I don't have access to the ``<T>``, i only have the ``Type`` ..if that makes sense

Comment: @KyleGobel extended my answer to show how to resolve the generic method dynamically.

Comment: awesome, thanks, didn't even cross my mind to call the third party method with reflection like that

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
void DoWork(IEnumerable items, Type type)
    {
        // instance of object you want to call
        var thirdPartyObject = new ThirdPartyObject();
        // create a list with type "type"
        var typeOfList = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        // create an instance of the list and set items 
        // as constructor parameter
        var listInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(listOfTypes, items);
        // call the 3. party method via reflection, make it generic and
        // provide our list instance as parameter
        thirdPartyObject.GetType().GetMethod("ThirdPartyMethod")
            .MakeGenericMethod(type)
            .Invoke(thirdPartyObject, new []{listInstance});            
    }
```

The code creates a list instance of the generic type "type" (by using MakeGenericType). Your item elements are then copied to the list and the third party method is called via relection (note the "MakeGenericMethod" call to ensure that the method has the same type parameter as the method argument.