# Cast to IEnumerable<T> where T is a runtime type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

This is a weird problem that I've stumbled upon, involving reflection:

I create a `MyGenericType<T>` at runtime where `T` is a runtime type:

```
object genType = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyGenericType<>).MakeGenericType(runtimeType));
```

Then I need to pass it as an argument to another function which only accepts a `IEnumerable<runtimeType>`.

I can't use `dynamic` as `MyGenericType` only implements IEnumerable explicitly, not implicitly.

Is there anyway to cast to an `IEnumerable<runtimeType>`?

Comment: Why does it not implement `IEnumerable<T>` in the standard way?

Comment: It's somebody else's library. It is what it is.

Comment: As it happens I did find a way around it, but I am wondering if there's a neater solution.

Comment: maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599314/casting-an-ienumerable-to-ienumerablet-with-reflection

Comment: Can you not invoke the method using reflection?

Answer (score 3):

Create a generic caller method and invoke that instead.  In my code sample, the CallMethod is invoked via reflection and that method invokes the method that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type runtimeType = typeof(string);

    object genType = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyGenericType<>).MakeGenericType(runtimeType));

    var genericMethod = ((Action<MyGenericType<object>>)CallMethod)
        .Method
        .GetGenericMethodDefinition()
        .MakeGenericMethod(runtimeType)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] { genType });
}

static void CallMethod<T>(MyGenericType<T> myGeneric)
{
    MyEnumerableMethod((IEnumerable<T>)myGeneric);
}
```